# Select without FROM but with more than one rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How can I produce a table with 2 rows and 2 columns without selecting from an existing table? What I'm looking for is a select statement that returns,

e.g.

```
 id | value
 ---------
 1  | 103
 2  | 556
```

Comment: Is there any meaning to select without From

Comment: There is meaning if you want to test e.g. some joins with dummy data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT 1 as id, 103 as value
UNION
SELECT 2 as id, 556 as value
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a685f/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UNION ALL`. Which is better choice then `UNION`

```
SELECT 1 as id, 103 as value
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as id, 556 as value
```

Answer (score 1):

Sybase answer, try something similar in mysql

```
select "1" as id,"103" as value
union
select "2" ,"556"
```

#### Result

`id | value`
 `----------`
 `1  | 103`
 `2  | 556`

Answer (score -1):

Unless you want to hard code the data into your SELECT statement you will need to SELECT from a table.